# Possible configurations of rational curves on a rational surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Consider a set of smooth rational curves on a rational surface, say, with normal crossings between curves. Is anything known on what combinatorics of configurations are possible?

Say, what obstructions are known to finding the rational curves with fixed graph of incidence and fixed self-intersections numbers?

I understand that its matrix of incidence should be embeddable into $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ with standard form of signature $(1, n)$, (in particular, have s̶i̶g̶n̶a̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶1̶  index at most 1). Are there any other obstructions?

Comment: What is this statement about signature 1? What if you take two disjoint $(-1)$-curves?

Comment: Oh, I meant at most one positive coordinate, it is the direct implication of Hodge's theorem on index. I will fix it now.

Comment: This is known as "positive index of inertia"; the signature is the difference of the positive and negative indices.

Comment: The question is very vague. Is the surface fixed? Are the curves assumed to be irreducible? What does "a couple of curves" mean? Do you want to record the intersection indices or just geometric intersections in your "graph/matrix of incidence"? Etc.

Comment: Surface not fixed. I would like curves to be smooth, and I think geometric intersections coincide with intersection indices due to transversality assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Re your last remark: two smooth curves may transversally intersect at multiple points (e.g. a line and a conic in the plane have intersection index 2) . The adjacency matrix of the "graph of incidence" is a (0,1)-matrix, but to get obstructions from the Neron-Severi group you need to consider the intersection matrix, which contains more information.

Comment: Yeah, or consider graph with multiple edges, it is the same.

Answer (score 3):

This question is addressed in Kollár's paper
[Simple normal crossing varieties with prescribed dual
complexes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1089.pdf). For a variety $X$
with a (reduced, effective) simple normal crossing divisor $\Delta \subset
X$, write $\Delta = \bigcup_{i} D_{i}$ where $D_{i} \subset D$ are the
components. The **dual complex** $D(X, \Delta)$ is the simplicial complex
with

- 0-cells corresponding to the components $D_{i}$
- 1-cells corresponding to the *non-empty* intersections
  $D_{i} \cap D_{j}$
- 2-cells corresponding to the *non-empty* intersections $D_{i} \cap
  D_{j} \cap D_{k}$

and so on. (Part of) theorem 1 of that paper shows that given any
simplicial complex $\mathcal{C}$ of dimension $n-1$ there is a smooth,
projective, rational variety $X$ and a simple normal crossing divisor
$\Delta \subset X$ with rational components so that $D(X, \Delta)
\simeq C$ (*isomorphism*, not homotopy equivalence!).

When $X$ is a surface, the triple intersections are automatically
empty, so $D(X, \Delta)$ is a graph, the **dual graph** if you
will. So in this case the theorem says any 1-dimensional simplicial
complex can be realized as the dual graph of a simple normal crossing
divisor with rational components on a smooth rational surface.

**Remark**: the theorem I cited holds in all dimensions; it's
quite possible that there's an easier way to prove the result for
surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for linking this - I was aware of this paper but I guess I forgot about it somehow. There is indeed a way to prove this easier for surfaces - consider n rational curves of high enough degree in general position and blow up the points you don't like. My question seems to be more about canonical class question in Kollar's paper - what are possible self-intersections for a given graph.

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I don't think I can be of help with the canonical/self intersections in this case. Best of luck with it!